# nginx fast-cgi only certain php files

Tags: nginx

I have a working nginx/php-fpm setup working, but I need to proxy certain php files to another server. Here is what I have that doesn't seem to be working

```
# clisupp and other supporting files
  location /swsupport/ {
    add_header X-debug-message "Proxied" always;
    proxy_pass http://swsupport;
  }

location ~ \.php$ {
      add_header X-debug-message "A php file was used" always;
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
```

When a request like `http://localhost/swsupport/clisupp/swtoday/index.php` is made it is handled by the `php` location and not the `/swsupport/` location. Here is a picture of an actual example. As you can see the `X-debug-message` header corresponding to the php location was used.

[image]

Comment: Try: `location ^~ /swsupport/ { ... }`

Comment: That worked. If you want the credit post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *regular expression* `location` takes precedence over a normal prefix `location` unless the `^~` modifier is used.

In your configuration, URIs beginning with `/swsupport/` and ending with `.php` were still being handled by the `location ~ \.php$` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /swsupport/ { ... }
```